# Why should I replace "Despite" in this sentence with "While"?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

Why should I replace `Despite` in this sentence with `While`?

Wrong:

> Despite this book is useful, many students have not started reading it.

Correct:

> While this book is useful, many students have not started reading it.

Comment: Well, if you want to keep *despite*, you need to change *is* to *being*.

Comment: Alternatively, "Despite the fact that this book is useful..."

Comment: You can use "although" or "even though" instead of "while".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Despite](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/in-spite-of-and-despite)** and **in spite of** are prepositional expressions having the same meaning and are interchangeable. They are used in sentences to express a contrast between two things. They are used only with nouns or ing forms and never *in spite of / despite + clause*. **While** can be used in clauses to balance a contrast.

The sentence should be rewritten using **despite** as:

***Despite the book's being useful, many students have not started reading it.***

Comment: _In spite of_ and _despite_ are not always interchangeable; when the object is a participial clause with no explicit subject, for example, only _despite_ works: “Despite being drunk, he still managed to walk straight” is fine, whereas “In spite of being drunk, he still managed to walk straight” is dubious at best (completely ungrammatical to me).

Comment: @Janus I'd drop the 'still' but find both equally acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You could write, "Despite the usefulness of the book, many student have not started reading it."

As Davo points out, using "is" with "despite" in the original text is awkward. Changing "despite" to "while" resolves this. Changing "is useful" to "the usefulness" also resolves this.I believe the issue is that "despite" is a preposition, and "while" is a conjunction.

> Noted by Janus Bahs Jacquet:
>
> A preposition... cannot be followed by a finite verb clause—prepositions generally cannot. It can be followed by a noun phrase (“despite the high prices”) or by a present participle phrase (“despite the prices being high”), but not a finite verb.
>
> Conjunctions like while, on the other hand, must be followed by a finite verb clause.

Comment: The question is why a native speaker replaced "despite" with "while" when he reviewed my writing? What is wrong with "Despite"?

Comment: @Stephen: "Despite this book is useful, ..." is wrong and something needs to be changed.  Your editor chose to change *Despite* though other possibilities also work

Comment: @Stephen As PV22 says, _despite_ is a preposition and as such cannot be followed by a finite verb clause—prepositions generally cannot. It can be followed by a noun phrase (“despite the high prices”) or by a present participle phrase (“despite the prices _being_ high”), but not a finite verb. Conjunctions like _while_, on the other hand, **must** be followed by a finite verb clause.

Comment: Actually, let me qualify that: there are a fair few prepositions that **can** be followed by finite verb clauses, at least in some people’s view; _despite_ just isn’t one of them. People like [Geoff Pullum](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494) consider both _despite_ and _while_ to be prepositions; conjunctions to them are only _and_, _but_, and _that_. Others would disagree.

Comment: Also, I do believe you’ve confused me with a small, West Indian nation. ;-)